# Plymouth main process killed by SEGV signal error on boot

Tags: 11.04, boot, plymouth

After upgrading to 11.04 the following messages appear, i don't know what to do about it. pls suggest.

```
init: plymouth main process (68) killed by SEGV signal
init: plymouth-splash main process (193) terminated with status 2
```

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a custom kernel then your solution is in:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/571258?comments=all